# Create multiple boolean columns in pandas dataframe based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I have a dataset, where authors are ranked by the order of authorship (1, 2, 3, etc).

```
Authorid    Author  Article Articleid   Rank
1            John   article 1   1        1
1            John   article 2   2        2
1            John   article 3   3        3
1            John   article 4   4        3
2            Mary   article 5   5        1
2            Mary   article 6   6        2
2            Mary   article 7   7        1
2            Mary   article 8   8        8
```

I want to create three more Boolean columns `If_first`, `If_second`, `If_last`.
The purpose of this - I want to show if the author is ranked 1, 2, or last in the article.
The `last` means the maximum number in `Rank` column (the maximum number for this `Authorid` in the column `Rank`).

I can do `If_first` and `If_second`, that is pretty easy, but not sure how to resolve `If_last`.

```
df.loc[df['Rank'] == 1, 'If_first'] = 1
df.loc[df['Rank'] != 1, 'If_first'] = 0
df.loc[df['Rank'] == 2, 'If_second'] = 1
df.loc[df['Rank'] != 2, 'If_second'] = 0
```

Two rules here

- `If_first` = `if_last` - treat him as `if_first`
- `If_second` = `if_last` - treat him as `if_second`

Expected output:

```
Authorid    Author  Article Articleid   Rank    If_first    If_second   If_last
1            John   article 1   1        1       1              0         0
1            John   article 2   2        2       0              1         0
1            John   article 3   3        3       0              0         1 (third is the last here)
2            Mary   article 5   5        1       1              0         0
2            Mary   article 6   6        2       0              1         0
2            Mary   article 7   7        3       0              0         0 (third is not the last here, because of the fourth below, all zeros)
2            Mary   article 8   8        4       0              0         1 (fourth is the last here)
```

Comment: Is there an extra row in the sample data? The last one in Authorid == 1?  It does not exist in your output. Or do we have to drop one of the rows if there are with the same rank within the same Authorid?

Comment: @sophocles, I updated the output again. If the 1,2,3 author is not the last - then all values must be zero. Somehow I need to calculate what is the max x rank for each author id and assign it to last. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
res = df.groupby('Authorid')['Rank'].apply(lambda x: [x.idxmin(), x.drop_duplicates()[1:].nsmallest(1).index[0], x.idxmax()])

df[['If_first', 'If_second', 'If_last']] = 0
df.loc[res.str[0].tolist(), 'If_first'] = 1
df.loc[res.str[1].tolist(), 'If_second'] = 1
df.loc[res.str[2].tolist(), 'If_last'] = 1
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  Authorid   Author  Article  Articleid  Rank  If_first  If_second  If_last
0     John  article        1          1     1         1          0        0
1     John  article        2          2     2         0          1        0
2     John  article        3          3     3         0          0        1
3     John  article        4          4     3         0          0        0
4     Mary  article        5          5     1         1          0        0
5     Mary  article        6          6     2         0          1        0
6     Mary  article        7          7     1         0          0        0
7     Mary  article        8          8     8         0          0        1
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to create a second dataframe grouped by `Articleid` collecting the statistic you're interested in:

```
df2 = df.groupby('Articleid').agg(mxrank=('Rank', 'max'))
```

then add the new column by merging the dataframes:

```
dfm = df.merge(df2, how='left', on='Articleid')
```

With example result (with some added rows to demonstrate an article "article4" with multiple ranks):

```
   Authorid Author   Article Articleid Rank mxrank
0         1   John  article1         1    1      1
1         1   John  article2         2    2      2
2         1   John  article3         3    3      3
3         1   John  article4         4    3      4
4         1    Foo  article4         4    1      4
5         1    Bar  article4         4    2      4
6         1    Baz  article4         4    4      4
7         2   Mary  article5         5    1      1
8         2   Mary  article6         6    2      2
9         2   Mary  article7         7    1      1
10        2   Mary  article8         8    8      8
```

Then compare the `mxrank` column to `Rank` to determine the flag for each row.